# Ad-hoc app always fails to install

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

So I having problems installing an ad-hoc distribution app on an ipad 1 with ios 5. I don't have this problem when installing in other ipads... here the console log after failing installation:

Mar 16 19:09:58 iPad SpringBoard[635] : Killing com.myapp.ipad for app installation

Mar 16 19:10:03 iPad ReportCrash[743] : Formulating crash report for process installd[739]

Mar 16 19:10:03 iPad com.apple.itunesstored[736] : receive_message: failure running async function: 1

Mar 16 19:10:03 iPad com.apple.itunesstored[736] : call_and_response: Could not receive response from proxy

Mar 16 19:10:03 iPad com.apple.itunesstored[736] : MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1

Mar 16 19:10:04 iPad ReportCrash[743] : Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/installd_2014-03-16-191003_iPad.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0

Mar 16 19:10:04 iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.mobile.installd[739]) : (com.apple.mobile.installd) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: 1. What is the deployment SDK that you are using to build the app? (iOS 5.1?) 2. Which architectures are included in the build? (armv7, armv7s, arm64 ?) 3. What is the content of the mentioned crash report?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem when distributing an Ad Hoc build via TestFlight. All my devices can install the build, except iPad 1. This problem started after upgrading to XCode 5.1, letting it adjust the architecture setting. My app supports armv7,armv7s and arm64 and has a deployment target of 5.0.

Comment: Is it posible that apple will no longer support Ipad 1 for ad hoc after xcode 5.1?

Comment: I have my hands on a third ipad 1 with ios 5.1.1 and it also fails to install when almost done downloading... I think apple has forsaken ipad 1 or ios 5 from ad hoc...

Comment: No, it should install on the iPad, if the provisioning profile have its UDID included.

Answer (score 5):

If your building settings support arm64, although UDID already in provisioning profile, problem still occur.  Just remove arm64 support will do.

Answer (score 3):

Check the ipa is 32 bit. 64 bit is not supported prior to iOS 6 and will fail to install.

You can see an error message for this behavior by dragging the ipa onto the Application node of an iPad running iOS 5 in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the iPad's DeviceID is listed in the developer portal as a registered device, that the ad-hoc provisioning profile includes that device and that the correct provisioning profile has been downloaded and used to sign the app.  Also make sure that when archiving the app, that you select the ad-hoc profile you have the device assigned to.

Edit, since we have more info the probable cause is that you are targeting an OS greater than the OS installed on the iPads.  Check your Project properties (General section):
[image: General]

Comment: There are 7 ipads, the app installs perfectly in 5 of them, both ipads that failed are Ipad 1 with ios 5.1.1 Coincidence?

Comment: No coincidence.  Your app must be targeting an OS greater than 5.1.1.  I have revised my answer and included a screenshot of what you need to check.

Comment: that ain't the issue either :S, the target is 5.1.1 and I can run the app on debug mode, the problem is with ad-hoc

Answer (score 1):

Check UDID. Now it possible to extract UDID only from xCode or iTunes, not from some special UDIDapp. If UDID is wrong - there is maybe FFFFF** in beginning.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the 64-bit issue was the apparent iPad1 problem if I understand now what 'arm64' means.

Removing arm64 from Targets>Build Settings>Valid Architecture immediately solved it.

After archiving an ipa and installing it from iTunes to a device I had been seeing only the icon, partially installed on the iPad1, but hanging with the blue thermometer progress bar at 75% indefinitely. This was when using an enterprise license so if user23...'s failure was at "icon time" then provisioning is probably unrelated. I see there are possibly 4 failure points:

1. Dragging ipa to iTunes. I think the drag is ignored if the code
   signing is flawed; dragging fails to add it to the library.
2. Dragging app from Library to device. I think this fails if the
   Deployment Target is higher than the device's OS.
3. Completing the installation of the app to the device. This is the level of the problem I had.
4. Launching app on device. In one test I had an app launch but appear blank; I think that was from when autolayout was on.

Regarding 64-bit, I had read in Jay Versluis's http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-build-apps-for-ios-5-with-xcode-5, 
"Choose 5.1.1 (manually) to support both 64 and 32 bit binaries – no need to change the default build architecture this way," so maybe that needs to be examined, not sure. (Maybe it's the difference between 'building for iOS 5' and 'building for iPad1'???)